# Magento How to use translation on attribute label?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I use Magento and I need help to use in frontend the translation of an attribute label !
I use this on my marketplace.phtml to load the attribute label

```
<?php
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'etat_verres');
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($allOptions as $instance) { if($instance['label']) {

echo $instance['value'] // to show the value
echo $instance["label"] // to show the label

} }

?>
```

The problem is that Magento use Admin Value and not french value or english value.

Thanks in advance !

Sincerely yours,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `$this->__` is the core Magento helper which also contains the translation functionality, now assuming your module has extends the core Magento helper this will work. Now you can use a theme translate.csv file to translate your text.

```
<?php
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'etat_verres');
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);

foreach($allOptions as $instance)
{
    if ($instance['label'])
    {
        echo $this->__($instance['value']) // to show the value
        echo $this->__($instance["label"]) // to show the label
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind, translating the "labels" should not be necessary as you can use the Magento admin store view translations within Catalog->Manage Attributes  Select your attribute and manage attributes per store view, however, I'm not entirely sure of the context.  While what I provided should work, having context will provide a better solution.